How can I populate a column with same values which is there in that column
I have the following table:

The flat_id column will only contain 2 distinct values i.e. 'ABC123' and 'NA'. I need to create a new column new_flat_id which will contain the 'ABC123' values in all rows which basically means replacing the 'NA' values.

How can it done using SQL?

Could you please explain more detailed your use case and the logic behind? You could just write SELECT...,'ABC123' AS new_flat_id..., but I guess your real situation is more complex than you are telling us?

Or you can write MIN(flat_id) OVER() AS new_flat_id, both produce the intended result. See https://dbfiddle.uk/Cqxr6GYq Please tell us a bit more ;)

I am learning SQL so if I am wrong then probably other would fix it,you can query something like below:
1.Add a column using DDL command
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD new_flat_id varchar(255);

2.Use DML command to query condition
UPDATE table_name
SET new_flat_id = CASE WHEN flat_id = 
'NA' THEN 'ABC123' ELSE flat_id END;


Beside that their description doesn't sound like they want to run an update command, you don't need a CASE. Since all rows should get ABC123 as new_flat_id, simply update to this value without any conditions. Or even better set this value as default value of the column while adding the column rather than updating the column afterwards.

Thank you for providing better look.But i tried to follow the description "replacing". The description doesn't provide clear logical explanation or use case.So I assume it.

Yes, they should of course improve their question, this would also help people with similar questions to find a solution.
